# eslint and nodejs console messages

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have just started to use `eslint` and when running part of my application that visits various web pages I get console Messages like so printed out in the console

```
ConsoleMessage {
 _type: 'warning',
 _text: 'Extra form data if value attribute is present with non-empty value for <input type=\'image\'> is deprecated and will be removed in M68, around July 2018. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5672688152477696 for more details.',
 _args: [] }
```

I have tried the following in my `.eslintrc.js`

```
"no-console": 0
```

But I still get these messages, how do I suppress this ?

Thanks

Comment: Setting `"no-console": 0` in your `.eslintrc.js` file will not prevent logging to the console, nor is it the aim of eslint.

Eslint is intended to force **you** to write code in a particular, preset manor specifically for style and consistency reasons, especially helpful in large open-source projects.

Disabling console logging, in your case, warn, is not recommended.

Ignoring this, you would still also need to show us your code to aid you in suppressing these messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message doesn't have anything todo with `eslint` and it's `no-console` rule. The message is a warning from Google Chrome about [some deprecated code](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5672688152477696).

As you point out you are 'visiting various websites' from within your application, I guess you are probably using something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) and the message might be output of [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-console). Which would imply it is a Google Chrome warning of deprecated code from a website you are visiting.

To answer your question about suppressing these messages, you shouldn't log these console events, however I can't be sure as I haven't seen your code.

Comment: Ah, I made the assumption based on the fact I only started seeing these messages after installing eslint. Yes I am using puppeteer. I'll look into it further, thank you

Comment: @Richlewis, did this answer your question?

Comment: Would you know how i stop these messages or where to start to look to stop logging these events ?

Comment: I think you have something similar to `page.on('console', msg => { console.log(msg); });` in your code somewhere, but I can't be for sure, as I haven't seen your code